# Using array map to concatenate letters in a string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, helper

I have a function `getChar` that takes 1 parameter - an array of words. I would like to concatenate the n<sup>th</sup> letter from the n<sup>th</sup> word and return them as a string. For example: `getChar(["javascript", "is cool", "123"])` should return value `js3`.

What's wrong?

```
function getChar(arr)
{
    return arr.mao(function(v,i,a){
        return v[i];
    }).join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Yep, what's wrong? You didn't tell us why you think it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your general algorithm is correct. Just a few typos.

If you aren't already aware, and this is your code indeed:

- Your code uses `mao` instead of `map`
- From your example test case, you want to cleanly concatenate the characters, not gluing them with a space. You should join with `""` instead.

The below code is tested from Google Chrome F12:

```
function getChar(arr){
  return arr.map(function(v,i,a){
    return v[i];
  }).join("");
}
console.log(getChar(["javascript", "iscool", "123"]));

< js3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just loop through the array?

```
function getChar(arr) {
    var string = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        string += arr[i][i]
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: Warning : If the 6th word only have 5 letters, it will return an undefined in the string like "itdoesntwundefinedorks"

Answer (score 0):

```
function getChar(arrayOfWords){
  var buffer = '';
  var result = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfWords.length; i++){
    buffer = arrayOfWords[i].split('');
    if(buffer[i]){
      result += buffer[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var arrayOfWords = ['JavaScript', 'React', 'Angular', 'JQuery', 'Ember', 'Node'];

var result = getChar(arrayOfWords);

console.log(result);
// It shows "Jeger"
```

1. Pass the array of string (words) as an argument of the getChar function.
2. For each word in the array, catch the nth char.
3. Push in in the result string (you can use += or .join()).
4. return the result string.

Edit : small fix about the nth letter choosed